# PHP multidimensional array sort by value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Regarding this multidimensional array:

```
[
(int) 7 => [
    (int) 0 => [
        (int) 0 => '12:45',
        (int) 1 => 'E1',
        (int) 2 => 'B EXTREME 30'
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        (int) 0 => '10:15',
        (int) 1 => 'E1',
        (int) 2 => 'B SHAPE 30'
    ],
],
(int) 1 => [
    (int) 0 => [
        (int) 0 => '09:30',
        (int) 1 => 'E2',
        (int) 2 => 'CYCLING VIRTUAL 50'
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        (int) 0 => '10:30',
        (int) 1 => 'E1',
        (int) 2 => 'BODY PUMP VIRTUAL 60'
    ],
    (int) 2 => [
        (int) 0 => '11:45',
        (int) 1 => 'E1',
        (int) 2 => 'BODY BALANCE VIRTUAL 60'
    ],
],
(int) 2 => [
    (int) 0 => [
        (int) 0 => '14:45',
        (int) 1 => 'E2',
        (int) 2 => 'CYCLING VIRTUAL 50'
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        (int) 0 => '17:00',
        (int) 1 => 'E1',
        (int) 2 => 'POSTURA ALONGAMENTO 60'
    ],
    (int) 2 => [
        (int) 0 => '09:15',
        (int) 1 => 'E1',
        (int) 2 => 'BODY PUMP 50'
    ],
]
]
```

The first key, of each first level array, are days of the week (day 7, day 1 and day 2).

The arrays inside each first level array contain hour (`09:45`), rooms (`E1`) and description (`B EXTREME 30`).

I tried to sort this multidimensional array by the second levels array hour value.
I used `usort()`, `ksort()`, `array_multisort()`, and some custom made functions for sorting the array as i need without luck.

The inside arrays must be sorted by ascending order, like this (example with day 2):

```
09:15 -> 14:45 -> 17:00
```

Does anyone knows how can i achieve this?

Comment: So you don't want to sort by key as the title states, but sort by the time in each sub-array?

Comment: Yes... i need to sort by the time. My apologies... i will edit the question.

Comment: Please post expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is called `$data`. Iterate the outer array, and apply a sort on each mid-level array, based on the time-part (in the innermost arrays). As your times are always formatted as "hh:ss", a string comparison in the `usort` callback does the job:

```
foreach ($data as &$events) {
    usort($events, function($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]);
    });
}
```

Note the `&` in the `foreach`: this makes sure you sort the original data, and not a copy of it.

If you want to create a *new* array, let's say `$result`, then do this (no `&` here!):

```
foreach ($data as $day => $events) {
    usort($events, function($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]);
    });
    $result[$day] = $events;
}
```

Comment: No luck, the result is an empty array.
$ar = [];
        foreach ($mapadeaulas_mobile as &$events) {
            usort($events, function($a, $b) {
                $ar = strcmp($a[0], $b[0]);
            });
        }

Comment: Works here: https://3v4l.org/TgMc6 What is `$ar`? This solution sorts the result in the *original* array. If you want the result in `$ar` , then first assign the array to `$ar` and do the `foreach` on `$ar`. Doing `$ar = strcmp(...)` makes no sense. You *must* `return strcmp(...)`

Comment: See addition to my answer.

Comment: Thank you. usort() plus strcmp() ordered the arrays by time in correct maner.

Answer (score 0):

`usort` — Sort an array by values using a user-defined comparison function.
Lets create a function where we compare time of two events.

This is part of your array

```
$array = [
    2 => [
        0 => [
            0 => '14:45',
            1 => 'E2',
            2 => 'CYCLING VIRTUAL 50'
        ],
        1 => [
            0 => '17:00',
            1 => 'E1',
            2 => 'BODY PUMP VIRTUAL 60'
        ],
        2 => [
            0 => '09:15',
            1 => 'E1',
            2 => 'BODY BALANCE VIRTUAL 60'
        ],
    ],
];
```

This is an example how to sort items for one day (day 2)

```
usort($array[2], function ($a, $b) {
    $time_a = strtotime($a[0]); // convert string to a unix timestamp to compare int
    $time_b = strtotime($b[0]);
    return $time_a - $time_b;
});
```

Output using `print_r($array);`

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 09:15
                    [1] => E1
                    [2] => BODY BALANCE VIRTUAL 60
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 14:45
                    [1] => E2
                    [2] => CYCLING VIRTUAL 50
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 17:00
                    [1] => E1
                    [2] => BODY PUMP VIRTUAL 60
                )

        )

)
```

To sort all days we do in a loop, passing each day array as a reference using `&`:

```
foreach ($array as &$day) {
    usort($day, function ($a, $b) {
        $time_a = strtotime($a[0]);
        $time_b = strtotime($b[0]);
        return $time_a - $time_b;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you nick, your answer is always good in sorting the array.